# Display name of many to many relation in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, portable-executable

I try to display the names of fields from a Model in my template.
This works fine with any type of fields except ManyToManyField.

I use this function in my models.py to return all fields.

```
def get_all_fields(self):
    """Returns a list of all field names on the instance."""
    fields = []

    # only display fields with values and skip some fields entirely
        if f.editable and value and f.name not in ('id','lastname','firstname') :
            fields.append(
                {
                'label':f.verbose_name,
                'name':f.name,
                'value':value,
                })
    return fields
```

In my template I use this loop to display all fields:

```
{% for f in modelname.get_all_fields %}
<td>{{f.label|capfirst}}</td><td>{{f.value|escape|urlize|linebreaks}}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

As mentioned before, this works fine with all fields except ManyToManyFields.
For example one of my M2M relations looks like this:

```
family = models.ManyToManyField('family', related_name="family", null=True, blank=True)
```

I'd be thankful for every hint that helps solving this.

Regards
Conrad

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify `verbose_name` argument for ManytoManyfield

```
family = models.ManyToManyField('family',verbose_name=u'trampampam', related_name="family", null=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You write `{{f.value|escape|urlize|linebreaks}}`, which displays the value of the field. However, the value of a M2M relation is a set of object instances and you need to iterate again over the set (if that is the result you want):

```
{% load m2m_filter %}

{% for f in modelname.get_all_fields %}
  <td>{{f.label|capfirst}}</td>
  <td>
    {% if f.value|is_m2m %}        
      {% for object in f.value.objects.all %}
        {{ object|escape|urlize|linebreaks }}
      {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
      {{f.value|escape|urlize|linebreaks}}
    {% endif %}
  </td>
{% endfor %}
```

and you also have to create the [filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters)

m2m_filter.py

```
from django import template
from django.db import models

register = template.Library()

def is_m2m(value):
    return type(value) == models.ManyToManyField *

register.filter('is_m2m', is_m2m)
```

* I guess, it's a different type; just check that

Comment: I get an error when I try to use the filter.
Invalid filter: 'is_m2m'

Comment: To be more specific, I try to check if a distinct field exists. `% if f.label == 'berufsschule' %} <td>{{f.label|capfirst}}</td><td><a href="{% url schule_detail teilnehmer.berufsschule.id %}" target="_blank">{{f.value|escape|urlize|linebreaks}}</a></td> {% else %} <td>{{f.label|capfirst}}</td><td>{{f.value|escape|urlize|linebreaks}}</td></tr>`